# Descobrir qual servico esta sendo usado em porta tcp C#

Tags: c#, winforms, tcp

Criei um Scan Port no C# (winforms), que esta verificando um faixa de portas, previamente setadas, consigo verificar que a porta esta aberta, mas meu problema é o seguinte: Eu sei que a porta esta aberta, mas não sei qual o tipo de serviço esta rodando nessa porta, existe alguma função ou biblioteca que eu consiga verificar qual serviço esta rodando nessas portas abertas??

```
public void StartScan(object o)
{
    IPAddress ipAddress = o as IPAddress;
    gridPortaAberta.Rows.Clear();


    for (int i = startPort; i <= endPort; i++)
    {
        lock (consoleLock)
        {

            label5.Text = "Scaneando Porta: " + i;
        }

        while (waitingForResponses >= maxQueriesAtOneTime)
            Thread.Sleep(0);

        if (stop)
            break;

        try
        {
            Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                                  SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);


            //Representa um ponto de extremidade de rede como um endereço IP e um número de porta.
            s.BeginConnect(new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, i), EndConnect, s);

            Interlocked.Increment(ref waitingForResponses);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }
}

public void EndConnect(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        DecrementResponses();

        List<string> items = new List<string>();

        Socket s = ar.AsyncState as Socket;

        s.EndConnect(ar);

        if (s.Connected)
        {
            int openPort = Convert.ToInt32(s.RemoteEndPoint.ToString().Split(':')[1]);

            openPorts.Add(openPort);


            gridPortaAberta.Rows.Add(openPort.ToString());

            lock (consoleLock)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("TCP conectado na porta: { 0}", openPort);
            }

            s.Disconnect(true);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
}

public void IncrementResponses()
{
    Interlocked.Increment(ref waitingForResponses);

    PrintWaitingForResponses();
}

public void DecrementResponses()
{
    Interlocked.Decrement(ref waitingForResponses);

    PrintWaitingForResponses();
}

public void PrintWaitingForResponses()
{
    lock (consoleLock)
    {

        label6.Text = "Esperando respostas de " + waitingForResponses + " threads";


    }
}
```

Comment: se puder mostrar o código que você está trabalhando... ajuda

Comment: Postei o código amigo, sera q existe alguma forma de fazer essa verificação??

Comment: você basicamente está tentando conectar na porta... se der errado é porque está sendo usada. Recomendo ver esse código, utiliza o executavel do windows para ler as portas e você consegue ter mais informações: http://www.cheynewallace.com/get-active-ports-and-associated-process-names-in-c/

Comment: há essa outra forma, fazendo a aplicação na mão, utilizando a API do windows: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4298/Getting-active-TCP-UDP-connections-on-a-box

Comment: obg amigo, vi os projetos aqui, creio que vai dar certinho para o que preciso, muito obggg

Answer (score 1):

Voce pode usar o `netstat -b` para obter esta informacao. Voce pode executar esse comando com o `Process.Start` e ler o output retornado pelo nestat para obter as informacoes do par processo + porta. Fiz um pequeno exemplo.

```
public class UsedPort
{
    public int Port { get; set; }
    public string Process { get; set; }
}
public static IEnumerable<UsedPort> GetUsedPorts()
{
    var process = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("netstat", "-anb")
    {
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false
    });
    string line = null;
    while ((line = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.IndexOf("TCP") >= 0 || line.IndexOf("UDP") >= 0)
        {
            var row = line.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            var localAddress = row[1];
            var processName = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
            if(!processName.Contains("Can not obtain ownership information")){
                yield return new UsedPort
                {
                    Port = int.Parse(localAddress.Split(':').Last()),
                    Process = processName
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito obg amigo, a tarde vou implementar e posto o resultado aqui... muito obg mesmo, tenha um bom dia